# grunt-contrib-less: compilation on watch task removes sourcemap link

Tags: less, source-maps, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-less

Here's my less task config:

```
less: {
    development: {
        options: {
            compress: false,
            sourceMap: true,
            yuicompress: true,
            sourceMapFilename: 'export/style/app.css.map',
            sourceMapURL: '/style/app.css.map'
        },

        files: {
            "export/style/app.css": "less/app.less"
        }
    }
},
```

If I just type `grunt less`, in my compiled file i get the `/*# sourceMappingURL=/style/app.css.map */` comment correctly.

Instead, when i run `grunt` and my watch task kicks in, the `/*# sourceMappingURL=/style/app.css.map */` comment is removed on compilation.

Here's my watch task for less:

```
watch: {
    less: {
        files: ['less/*.less'],
        tasks: ['less', 'postcss'],
        options: {
            livereload: true,
            nospaces: true
        }
    }
},
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your watch task also mentions `postcss` task that you seem to also use to process your css, do you? That's the trick - make sure *all* tools in your CSS processing chain can propagate the initial source-map correctly (and have the corresponding options on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was actually the `postcss` task preventing the comment to appear. fixed with

```
postcss: {
    options: {
      map: true,
```